# Near "S1": (vcom-1576) expecting BEGIN

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

Hello I'm new at modelsim and I don't know how to use it properly and I it pops me this error.

```
near "S1": (vcom-1576) expecting BEGIN.
```

**---CODE---**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test_mux is 
end test_mux;


architecture test_b of test_mux is
signal A1, B1: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
 S1: std_logic;
 D1: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
component mux_double_2to1 port (a, b, s: in bit; d: out bit);
end component; 
begin 
M1: mux_double_2to1 PORT MAP (a=>A1,b=>B1,s=>S1,d=>D1);
process
begin
A1 <= '001';B1 <= '010';S1 <= '0'; wait for 20 ps;
A1 <= '010';B1 <= '100';S1 <= '0'; wait for 20 ps;
A1 <= '111';B1 <= '011';S1 <= '0'; wait for 20 ps;
A1 <= '101';B1 <= '111';S1 <= '0'; wait for 20 ps; 
A1 <= '010';B1 <= '001';S1 <= '1'; wait for 20 ps;
A1 <= '000';B1 <= '101';S1 <= '1'; wait for 20 ps; 
A1 <= '101';B1 <= '010';S1 <= '1'; wait for 20 ps;
A1 <= '111';B1 <= '101';S1 <= '1'; wait for 20 ps;  
end process; 
end test_b;
```

**---ENTITY---**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux_double_2to1 is port(
     a, b: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); 
     s: in std_logic;
     d: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0));
end mux_double_2to1;
```

Also entity is compiled sucessfully. What should I do about that? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Inside the architecture, you missed the keyword `signal` infront of `S1` and `D1`

Comment: You call only one time signal. It is not working every time. It pops more errors if you do that

Comment: VHDL parses by looking at the next token. Following the signal declaration for A1 and B the next token can be one of the reserved words distinguishing block declarative items unambiguously (IEEE Std 1076-2008 3.3.2 Architecture declarative part) or the reserved word begin signifying the end of the block declarative part and the beginning of the architecture statement part. The identifier S1 isn't a reserved word so you'd either expect begin or you'd expect S1 to be preceded by a reserved word (here signal you use the compound delimiter <= in assignment to S1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello someone from my school help me to fix my issue so here is the complete solution.
Thanks whoever tried to help me. I appreciate it

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test_mux is 
end test_mux;
architecture test_b of test_mux is
signal A1, B1, D1: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal S1: std_logic;
component mux_double_2to1 port (a, b, d: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); s: out std_logic);
end component; 
begin 
M1: mux_double_2to1 PORT MAP (a=>A1,b=>B1,s=>S1,d=>D1);
process
begin
A1 <= "001";B1 <= "010";S1 <= '0'; wait for 20 ps;
A1 <= "010";B1 <= "100";S1 <= '0'; wait for 20 ps;
A1 <= "111";B1 <= "011";S1 <= '0'; wait for 20 ps;
A1 <= "101";B1 <= "111";S1 <= '0'; wait for 20 ps; 
A1 <= "010";B1 <= "001";S1 <= '1'; wait for 20 ps;
A1 <= "000";B1 <= "101";S1 <= '1'; wait for 20 ps; 
A1 <= "101";B1 <= "010";S1 <= '1'; wait for 20 ps;
A1 <= "111";B1 <= "101";S1 <= '1'; wait for 20 ps;  
end process; 
end test_b;
```